# "_blank" not working for TargetFrame property of button in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, oracle12c

I have seen a lot of posts on how to open a new tab/window in the browser. Most of them recommend setting the property `target = _blank` for the button, which I did (I used `TargetFrame=_blank`). It still opens the link in the same window/tab. I have also tried using a number of browsers but all gave the same results. I believe it could be an Oracle 12c issue. Most of the accepted answers I've seen for the `_blank` recommendation predate Oracle 12c. How can I solve this?

**UPDATE**

The source for the button:

```
<af:button text="report" id="b1"
binding="#{backingBeanScope.Backing.reportButton}"
action="#{backingBeanScope.Backing.urlConcatenatioinForReporting}"
targetFrame="_blank"
destination="#{backingBeanScope.Backing.URLToDisplayInBrowser}"
windowModalityType="modeless"
useWindow="true"/>
```

The method for the button:

```
private String URLToDisplayInBrowser; //This has its accessors 

public String urlConcatenatioinForReporting() {
    String URL = "http://localhost:7101/";
    String destination = URL+textToAppendToReportUrl;
    setURLToDisplayInBrowser(destination);

    try {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(URLToDisplayInBrowser);
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide complete code for this button component?

Comment: @Nagh I just updated the question with the button code

Answer (score 0):

You just messed up whole thing.
I'm not sure that you really need binding, but leaving it for now intact
 `action` or `actionListener` is useless, since destination property will overcome.
From documentation:

> destinatnion - the URI this component references when activated. This is an
>   alternative to using an action, with the **destination taking precedence**
>   when both are set.

`useWindow` and `windowModality` is for popups.

Now what happening, first is button reading value for `destination` from getter and it is empty now, so `destination` property disabled. Now `action` will kick in. In `action` (method `urlConcatenatioinForReporting`) you set your attribute for `destination`, however it won't be readed now and then  you force external redirect with this code: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(URLToDisplayInBrowser);`, which will take the place. So when you press your button, you will be redirected inside current tab to the URL provided in string `URLToDisplayInBrowser`

So what you actually need to do:

```
<af:button text="report" id="b1"
binding="#{backingBeanScope.Backing.reportButton}"
targetFrame="_blank"
destination="#{backingBeanScope.Backing.urlToDisplayInBrowser}"/>
```

Your bean code:

```
// note: properties names should start from lowercase
private String urlToDisplayInBrowser; //This has its accessors 
public String getUrlToDisplayInBrowser(){
  // FIXME: Setting it to some constant for testing purpose
  urlToDisplayInBrowser = "http://www.google.com";
  return urlToDisplayInBrowser;
}
```

Now it should work properly. Try it, then modify bean code according to your needs.